How to create a centered popup message in JavaScript after form submission?
I'm creating a form where users can input their feelings, select a mood with a slider, and add additional details. After they submit the form, I want to display a popup in the center of the screen with the data they entered. The popup should have two buttons: "Undo" to clear the form and close the popup, and "Confirm" to proceed with the submission. I am having trouble adjusting it to my original code and I would like some advice as to what I am doing wrong.
function submitEmotion() {
    var feelingText = document.getElementById('feelingText').value;
    var moreFeelings = document.getElementById('moreFeelings').value;
    var moodValue = document.getElementById('sliderValue').innerText;

    showPopup(feelingText, moodValue, moreFeelings);
}

function showPopup(feelingText, moodValue, moreFeelings) {
    
    var popupContent = `
        <h2>Your Response</h2>
        <div>
            <p><strong>You feel: ${feelingText}</strong></p>
            <p><strong>Mood: </strong>${moodValue}</p>
            <p><strong>More details: </strong>${moreFeelings}</p>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-top: 20px;">
            <button id="undoButton">Undo</button>
            <button id="confirmButton">Confirm</button>
        </div>
    `;

  
    var popupDiv = document.createElement('div');
    popupDiv.setAttribute('id', 'popupMessage');
    popupDiv.innerHTML = popupContent;

    
    var overlay = document.createElement('div');
    overlay.setAttribute('id', 'popupOverlay');
    overlay.appendChild(popupDiv);
    
    
    document.body.appendChild(overlay);

    
    document.getElementById('undoButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
        resetForm();
        document.body.removeChild(overlay);
    });

    
    document.getElementById('confirmButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
        confirmSubmission();
        document.body.removeChild(overlay);
    });
}

function resetForm() {
    document.getElementById('feelingText').value = '';
    document.getElementById('moreFeelings').value = '';
    document.getElementById('sliderValue').innerHTML = "Neutral";
    document.getElementById('mySlider').value = 3;
}

function confirmSubmission() {
    var feelingText = document.getElementById('feelingText').value;
    var moreFeelings = document.getElementById('moreFeelings').value;
    var moodValue = document.getElementById('sliderValue').innerText;

    
    console.log('Data saved:', feelingText, moodValue, moreFeelings);
}

Full code:
 <?php

session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION["user_id"])) {
    $mysqli = require __DIR__ . "/database.php";
    
    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM emote_meter WHERE user_id = ?";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $_SESSION["user_id"]);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    
    
    $user = $result->fetch_assoc();
}

?>
 <!doctype html> 
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.5/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/custom-style.css">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/just-validate@latest/dist/just-validate.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="validation.js" defer></script>
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
    <title>EmotControl</title>
    
    
</head>
<body>

  
<?php if (isset($user)): ?>
  
  
        <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="brand-title">Hello <?= htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["user_id"]) ?> how are you feeling today</div>
        <a href="#" class="toggle-button">
          <span class="bar"></span>
          <span class="bar"></span>
          <span class="bar"></span>
        </a>
        <div class="navbar-links">
 <ul>
    
    <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<style>
    svg a{
        text-decoration: none;
    }
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/index.css">
<div class="svg-container">

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 1000 1000" width="600px">
  <defs>
    <circle id="c1" stroke-width="250" fill="none" r="375" pathLength="360" stroke-dasharray="30 360"/></defs>
  <g transform="translate(500 500) rotate(-90)" font-size="33" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle">
    <a href="#" onclick="updateFeelingText(1)" transform="rotate(0)"><title>Excitement</title><use href="#c1" stroke="white"/><image xlink:href="emotess\exci.png" width="150px" height="150px"   transform="rotate(15) translate(430 -80) rotate(75)"></image></a>
    <a href="#" onclick="updateFeelingText(2)" transform="rotate(30)"><title>Inspiration</title><use href="#c1" stroke="white"/><image xlink:href="emotess\inspi.png" width="150px" height="150px"   transform="rotate(15) translate(390 -100) rotate(45)"></image></a>
    <a href="#" onclick="updateFeelingText(3)" transform="rotate(60)"><title>Joy</title><use href="#c1" stroke="white"/><image xlink:href="emotess\joy.png" width="150px" height="150px"   transform="rotate(15) translate(340 -75) rotate(15)"></image></a>
    <a href="#" onclick="updateFeelingText(4)" transform="rotate(90)"><title>Curiosity</title><use href="#c1" stroke="white"/><image xlink:href="emotess\curious.png" width="150px" height="150px"   transform="rotate(15) translate(310 -50) rotate(-15)"></image></a>>
    <a href="#" onclick="updateFeelingText(5)" transform="rotate(120)"><title>Pride</title><use href="#c1" stroke="white"/><image xlink:href="emotess\pride.png" width="150px" height="150px"   transform="rotate(15) translate(300 -10) rotate(-45)"></image></a>
    <a href="#" onclick="updateFeelingText(6)" transform="rotate(150)"><title>Hope</title><use href="#c1" stroke="white"/><image xlink:href="emotess\hope.png" width="150px" height="150px"   transform="rotate(15) translate(310 40) rotate(-75)"></image></a>
    <a href="#" onclick="updateFeelingText(7)" transform="rotate(180)"><title>Stress</title><use href="#c1" stroke="white"/><image xlink:href="emotess\stress.png" width="150px" height="150px"   transform="rotate(15) translate(330 80) rotate(-105)"></image></a>
    <a href="#" onclick="updateFeelingText(8)" transform="rotate(210)"><title>Panic</title><use href="#c1" stroke="white"/><image xlink:href="emotess\panic.png" width="150px" height="150px"   transform="rotate(15) translate(390 100) rotate(-135)"></image></a>
    <a href="#" onclick="updateFeelingText(9)" transform="rotate(240)"><title>Relief</title><use href="#c1" stroke="white"/><image xlink:href="emotess\relief.png" width="150px" height="150px"   transform="rotate(15) translate(430 90) rotate(-165)"></image></a>
    <a href="#" onclick="updateFeelingText(10)"transform="rotate(270)"><title>Confusion</title><use href="#c1" stroke="white"/><image xlink:href="emotess\confused.png" width="150px" height="150px"   transform="rotate(15) translate(460 50) rotate(165)"></image></a>
    <a href="#" onclick="updateFeelingText(11)"transform="rotate(300)"><title>Boredom</title><use href="#c1" stroke="white"/><image xlink:href="emotess\boredom.png" width="150px" height="150px"   transform="rotate(15) translate(480 10) rotate(135)"></image></a>
    <a href="#" onclick="updateFeelingText(12)"transform="rotate(330)"><title>Disappointment</title><use href="#c1" stroke="white"/><image xlink:href="emotess\dis.png" width="150px" height="150px"   transform="rotate(15) translate(470 -60) rotate(105)"></image></a>
    <a href="#" onclick="updateFeelingText('neutral')"><circle r="250" fill="white"/><title>Neutral</title><image xlink:href="emotess\neutral.png" width="480px" height="480px" transform="rotate(90) translate(-242 -242)"></img></a>
</g>
</svg>
</div>
<script>
   function updateFeelingText(emotion) {
    var emotionText = '';
    var bgColor = ''; 
    switch(emotion) {
        case 1:
            emotionText = 'Excitement';
            bgColor = '#FF5733'; 
            break;
        case 2:
            emotionText = 'Inspiration';
            bgColor = '#FFFF00'; 
            break;
        case 3:
            emotionText = 'Joy';
            bgColor = '#FFEB3B';
            break;
        case 4:
            emotionText = 'Curiosity';
            bgColor = '#8BC34A'; 
            break;
        case 5:
            emotionText = 'Pride';
            bgColor = '#9C27B0'; 
            break;
        case 6:
            emotionText = 'Hope';
            bgColor = '#4CAF50'; 
            break;
        case 7:
            emotionText = 'Stress';
            bgColor = '#FF5722'; 
            break;
        case 8:
            emotionText = 'Panic';
            bgColor = '#F44336'; 
            break;
        case 9:
            emotionText = 'Relief';
            bgColor = '#8BC34A'; 
            break;
        case 10:
            emotionText = 'Confusion';
            bgColor = '#9E9E9E'; 
            break;
        case 11:
            emotionText = 'Boredom';
            bgColor = '#607D8B'; 
            break;
        case 12:
            emotionText = 'Disappointment';
            bgColor = '#FF9800'; 
            break;
        case 'neutral':
            emotionText = '';
            bgColor = '#ffffff'; 
            break;
        default:
            emotionText = 'Unknown';
            bgColor = '#ffffff'; 
    }

    document.getElementById('feelingText').value = emotionText;

    
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = bgColor; 
}  
</script>
    
    <div class="feelingText">
    <lable for="feelingText"> I feel</lable>
    <input type="text" id="feelingText" class="updatedText" name="emotion" readonly >
    </div>
    <div class="textarea-title">Write more about your feelings</div>
    <div class="morefeelings">
<textarea type="text" id="moreFeelings" class="moreFeelings"  name="note" resize="none"   placeholder="WRITE HERE..."></textarea></div>
<div class="Submit-button">
  <button type="submit" onclick="submitEmotion()" style="background-color: #008CBA;">Submit</button>
</div>
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
      <input type="range" min="1" max="5" value="3" class="slider" id="mySlider" name="mood">
      <p>Mood: <span id="sliderValue">Neutral</span></p>
    </div>
    <script>
  
        function submitEmotion() {
            var feelingText = document.getElementById('feelingText').value;
            var moreFeelings = document.getElementById('moreFeelings').value;
            var moodValue = document.getElementById('sliderValue').innerText;

            showConfirmationMessage(feelingText, moodValue, moreFeelings);
        }

        function showConfirmationMessage(feelingText, moodValue, moreFeelings) {
            var overlay = document.createElement('div');
            overlay.setAttribute('id', 'confirmationOverlay');

            var confirmationDiv = document.createElement('div');
            confirmationDiv.setAttribute('id', 'confirmationMessage');
            confirmationDiv.innerHTML = `
                <h2>Your Response</h2>
                <div>
                    <p><strong>You feel: ${feelingText}</strong></p>
                    <p><strong>Mood: </strong>${moodValue}</p>
                    <p><strong>More details: </strong>${moreFeelings}</p>
                </div>
                <div style="margin-top: 20px;">
                    <button id="undoButton">Undo</button>
                    <button id="confirmButton">Confirm</button>
                </div>
            `;

            overlay.appendChild(confirmationDiv);
            document.body.appendChild(overlay);

            document.getElementById('undoButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
                resetForm();
                document.body.removeChild(overlay);
            });

            document.getElementById('confirmButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
                confirmSubmission();
                document.body.removeChild(overlay);
            });
        }

        function confirmSubmission() {
            var feelingText = document.getElementById('feelingText').value;
            var moreFeelings = document.getElementById('moreFeelings').value;
            var moodValue = document.getElementById('sliderValue').innerText;

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', 'save_emotion.php', true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                }
            };
            xhr.send('emotion=' + encodeURIComponent(feelingText) + '&mood=' + encodeURIComponent(moodValue) + '&note=' + encodeURIComponent(moreFeelings));
        }

        function resetForm() {
            document.getElementById('feelingText').value = '';
            document.getElementById('moreFeelings').value = '';
            document.getElementById('sliderValue').innerHTML = "Neutral";
            document.getElementById('mySlider').value = 3;
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
        }
    

    
   

      
</script>


    

    
  

        <?php else: ?>
            
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/background_style.css">     
        <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="brand-title">WELCOME TO EMOTE CONTROL</div>
        <a href="#" class="toggle-button">
          <span class="bar"></span>
          <span class="bar"></span>
          <span class="bar"></span>
        </a>
        <div class="navbar-links">
 <ul>
    <li><a href="#" id="loginLink">Login</a></li>
    
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    
 </ul>
</nav>
        </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#loginLink").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 
        
        
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "login.php", 
            success: function(response){
                
                location.reload();
            },
            error: function(){
                
                alert("Error occurred during login.");
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
                
                <?php endif; ?>
       </body>
</html>


Why not use the <dialog> tag? It's very useful.
